# Are there any downsides to making a crontab update for an operating system?

Tags: unix, cron

If I have an application hosted on my server, I would like to automatized as most as possible. If it's not recommended, are there any other solutions except from doing it manually?

Comment: Are you asking about automatically updating a cronjob when installing a piece of software, or about automating updates using cron?

Comment: Hello, I'm asking about automating updates using cron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, why not? I'm assuming you mean (for Debian/Ubuntu) something like `0 3 * * * sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`.

For Debian-based distros (like Ubuntu and Pop!_OS) the colloquial advice is to use the `unattended-upgrades` [package](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades), but I believe this is only because it standardizes the way unattended/automatic upgrades are done on Debian based systems. For example, logs go in a certain spot, and I believe you can set it up to send an email if there's an issue/when an upgrade is completed.

Of course in either case there is risk that this breaks something while you are unable to get to the server to fix it. For example, upgrading MySQL Server on an Ubuntu server I had once, broke MySQL Server, as in refused to restart, so I had a service running on a cron schedule that was failing, but I had no idea since I had no idea MySQL Server wasn't running - and that wasn't even a headless upgrade. Upgrades can break things, is the TLDR.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Exactly this kind of cron that I want to do. I'm posting this question because I had a debate with my friend and he didn't recommend me to do this way because it can install unwanted dependences which is true, but at the same time, if I forgot to manually update the system, I think it is more hazardous than not updating at all.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would install unwanted dependencies, but I can see it installing breaking or otherwise buggy packages that turn your stable system into an unstable one, at the cost of having any potential security patches installed. I will say you get finer control over which packages are installed and how using `unattended-upgrades`, but for a home server I'm not sure I would bother. Here's a nice article on `unattended-upgrades` if you want more details: https://www.kolide.com/features/checks/ubuntu-unattended-upgrades